# Query returned successfully, but no results in pgadmin 4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, ubuntu-22.04

No matter what I run, it says "Query returned successfully in xx secs". But there is no result on the data output tab.

It doesn't matter what query I run, even the basic `Select * from table_name` does the same.

I must open a  new query tool window and run the same query until I get the result. Even if I get it, that is one time. when I execute the same query a second time on that tab, It fails again saying Query returned successfully.

**I am using pgAdmin 4 on Ubuntu 22.04.**

[image: IMAGE SHOWING THE ISSUE]

Can someone please help me?

Comment: You have the "Messages" tab selected. Click on the "Data Output" tab.

Comment: The "Data Output" tab shows empty or the previous result.  The "Messages" tab will have something like this "__Successfully run. Total query runtime: 1 secs 340 msec. 10 rows affected__ " if the query is executed successfully.

Comment: Use [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) and spend more time getting constructive work done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I came across your question trying to find an answer to the same issue. In further searching, I managed to locate an explanation and workaround for the issue, and wanted to share in case you were still plagued by it.

I found a [bug thread](https://github.com/pgadmin-org/pgadmin4/issues/6163) for a problem in PgAdmin4 v7 that manifests similar to your description (and my own experience). Some manifestations seem related to timeouts and out of memory issues, but there were also issues related to the Autocompletion settings.

- Specifically, multiple users observed that if the `Autocomplete on key press` setting was enabled, queries would display a completion message, but show an empty results pane.

The PgAdmin team is investigating a fix, but in the meantime, there are two confirmed workarounds:

- Workaround 1: Rollback to PgAdmin v6.21; I have not tried this myself, but users in the issue thread indicate that query functionality returns to normal after rolling back.
- Workaround 2: Update the PgAdmin AutoComplete settings (File->Preferences->Auto Completion) so that `Autocomplete on key press` is off/disabled. Along with the users who reported this workaround, I can personally confirm that doing this fixed the problem for me.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I had the same issue, thanks for posting this. It worked fine with the latest version, 7.7

Comment: Thanks for the update, @GuiDadald; I have been meaning to check if it's been fixed.